# Getting blank page when using dropdown for displaying the job list in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am having a job portal page where i will be displaying the list of the jobs and the users can apply for the jobs posted by clicking on apply now button  a form will be where they need to fill their details etc..
The form contains position they are applying for, Name,Email,Mobile Number etc...
Position will be fetched automatically when clicking on applynow button.
Here i need to display all then jobs list in dropdown and the one which i have selected should be the first one in the text box but from my code it is displaying the total page as empty not displaying anything when we click on apply now..

Displaying the appplynow button(View):

```
 <div class="applynow"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>career/apply/<?php echo $r->jobs_id;?>" class="applyforjob">Apply Now</a></div>
 <div class="moreinfo" id="music" >More Info</div>
```

Controller(career/apply):

```
function apply($job_id)
{
    $this->load->model('career_model');
    $this->load->model('apply_model');
    $data['joblist']=$this->apply_model->jobs_dropdown();
    $data['records2']= $this->career_model->getcareerdatas($job_id);        
    $data['mainpage']='apply';      
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

View:

```
            <form name="applynow"  id="applynow" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>apply/applynow" >              
            <div class ="applyus">  
            <?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
            <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>              
            <div class="applyposition ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control positionapplied" name="positionapplied" id="positionapplied " value="<?php echo $r->job_name ;?>" readonly>  
            <?php
            $joblist['']='--Select Category --';    
            $jobs_id="id='jobs_id' ";   
            echo form_dropdown('jobs_id',$joblist,$r->jobs_id,$jobs_id);    
            ?>                              
            </div>  
            <?php endforeach;endif;?>                               
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-success successss" id="sub" >Submit</button>  
            <a  class="button cancel cancels" href="<?php echo site_url()?>career">Cancel</a>       
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="reset">                        
            </div>
            </form>
```

Model(apply_model):

```
function jobs_dropdown()    
{       
    $this->table = 'jobs_list';     
    $this->where('status',1);       
    $joblist=$this->dropdown('jobs_id','job_name');     
    return $joblist;
}
```

In Error_Log got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Apply_model::where() in /home/website/public_html/staging/application/models/apply_model.php on line 99
```

Comment: check your `error_log` and paste the error message in your question

Comment: @delboy1978uk updated with error message

Comment: your Apply_model doesn't have a where() method. Did you forget to extend some other class?

Comment: @delboy1978uk it is showing the error in this line $this->where('status',1); which i have included in jobs_dropdown

Comment: What class does your file extend?

Comment: @delboy1978uk function jobs_dropdown()     this is the function which i have written in model

Comment: which class does your model extend?

Comment: @delboy1978uk not getting you

Comment: I can see that. `class MyModel extends Something` What is the something?

Comment: @delboy1978uk class Apply_model extends CI_Model

Comment: CI_Model doesn't have a where() method https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/fced25f5728ce81fe810216fcaa4ccec7523f6c9/system/core/Model.php

Comment: @delboy1978uk i have changed to MY_Model tll it is displaying the same

Comment: Don't do that, put it back.

Comment: @delboy1978uk Just i tried whether it works or not like that

Comment: @user6728960 your model name should be `Apply_model` and check class name as well as that also should me `Apply_model`.

Answer (score 0):

From the CodeIgniter documentation:

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }
}
```

This will make the database class available through the $this->db object.

So then in your model, you access the where() clause like so:

`$this->db->where($blahblah);`

Check their tutorial here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: class Apply_model extends CI_Model
{
 function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database('jobs_list');
 }  function jobs_dropdown() 
 {  
  $this->table = 'jobs_list';  
  $this->db->where('status',1);  
  $joblist=$this->dropdown('jobs_id','job_name');  
  return $joblist;
 }

Comment: getting  blank page only

Comment: getting this error Call to undefined method Apply_model::dropdown()

Comment: Again, more missing methods. Apply_model doesn't have a dropdown() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Apply_model extends CI_Model 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default', true); 
    }
    function jobs_dropdown()    
    {       
        $this->table = 'jobs_list';     
        $this->where('status',1);       
        $joblist=$this->dropdown('jobs_id','job_name');     
        return $joblist;
    }
}
```

Save this as apply_model.php in application/model folder

Comment: can you please check whether data is returning from model to controller or not in $data['joblist'] array ?